# How to compare and get percentage of matching in oracle clob column?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table which has a clob column named description_note. What we need to do is to search through all and sort it by similarity. What we mean by similarity is suppose there are 3 texts like following -

```
Sample text abc
Sample text xyz
Different value
```

Both are in the table's clob column. We need to find the percentage matching of all the field values. Here, text 1 and 2 are similar, but 3  totally doesn't match.

How to sort the table in terms of similarity?